# Show another page when Amazon EC2 is stopped during night

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have an Amazon EC2 instance hosting a web application at `www.mywebapp.com`. The EC2 instance is stopped at 20:00 and started in the morning at 08:00. If someone visits `www.mywebapp.com` after 20:00 they will receive a blank page.

During the hours that the EC2 instance is stopped, I want to show an information page explaining that web app is online from 08:00 to 20:00 during week days only. How can I do that?

Is it possible for a Domain to point to a different machine during certain hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I should address the concept of a stoppage at night. If this is being done to save money, then there are some very low-cost instance types available (a couple of cents per hour) that you might choose to use instead of having a complete stoppage.

Another option is to use **spot instances** that can save up to 90%, and are typically easy to obtain at night. So, I would highly recommend investigating these options rather than turning off your service.

If you *do* wish to provide a notice at night, you could [Create Amazon Route 53 Health Checks and Configuring DNS Failover](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html).

Basically, you configure the domain name managed by Amazon Route 53 to perform a regular health check on the EC2 instance. If the health check fails, Route 53 can return an alternate target, such as a [static page in an Amazon S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html). Later, when the health check passes, it will change back to the original target instance.